# How to search array using unknown characters - Swift 3 for Mac

Tags: swift, macos, wildcard

I am looking for a way to search an Array of strings (containing filenames with extension) for dots (if the string contains characters-a dot-charaters, print the string definition). To do that I have to use something like wildcards (*.*).

So I tried this :

```
let testString = "*.*"
if Array[x].countains(testString)
{
print (Array[x])
}
```

or

```
if Array[x].range(of:testString) != nil
{
print (Array[x])
}
```

But it does not work. I guess I have to declare it differently but I don't know how and I have not found the right example.
Could someone shows some examples? Thank U.

Comment: It is Swift convention to name your vars starting with a lowercase letter. BTw Array is a Swift native structure type thus a terrible name for your var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this *helper method* on `String`:

```swift
extension String {
    func contains(regex: NSRegularExpression) -> Bool {
        let length = self.utf16.count // NSRanges are UTF-16 based!
        let wholeString = NSRange(location: 0, length: length)
        let matchCount = regex.numberOfMatches(in: self, range: wholeString)            
        return matchCount > 0
    }
}
```

Then try this:

```swift
let fileNameWithExtension = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\w+[.]\\w+")
if Array[x].contains(regex: fileNameWithExtension) {
    print(Array[x])
}
```

You may need to tweak my *pattern* above in order to match all cases you have in mind. This *[NSRegularExpression cheat sheet](https://koenig-media.raywenderlich.com/downloads/RW-NSRegularExpression-Cheatsheet.pdf)* might help you there ;-)

Comment: Ok, looks like you need a *regular expression* there ;-)

Comment: `matches` might be a better name for this function. Great work :0

Comment: @Alexander I was indeed using `matches` initially ;-) But since this is a *partial* match (ie, not the whole string), I changed to `contains` which somehow follows the same API naming style used by `String.contains(:String)` method as well. Anyway, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Oh you're write. Then `contains` is good, perhaps `contains(matching:)` too

Comment: Why not just `range(of: string, options: .regularExpression) != nil` ?

Comment: @LeoDabus That would be an macOS 10.12+ *only* API (or iOS 10+) on `String` type. Also, performance wise, wouldn't be a good choice since the regular expression needs to be re-compiled on every call. And, finally, creating the regex separately helps with (rookie) debugging a little IMHO ;-)

Comment: If you need the regex matches ranges converted for String you can check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43359456/swift-replace-first-occurrence-of-regex/43359558#43359558

Comment: Thanks a lot for this helpful example. I tested it inside a playground and it is working fine. Maybe you could help me to decode it? I wonder what is "location : 0" used for. Also, I have try to change the pattern to "\\w[.]\\w[.]\\w" in order to find strings containing several dots, but the answer is empty.

Comment: Try this instead: `"\\w([.]\\w)+"`

Comment: This worked : (pattern: "\\w[.]\\w+[.]"), even if I still don't know why... Anyway, now that I have all the components, it 'll be easier to study it further more. Thank U a lot for the quick and smart answer.

Comment: @Paulo Mattos, it's done. The last pattern you gave did not worked. It reported all the idem of the array.

Comment: Yeah, it can be tricky to design the perfect pattern :-( Pls look up the link in my answer for further help. Good luck!